# How to insert data in `catalog_category_product`?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, magento-1, model

I want to insert from magento Controller values to `catalog_category_product`. How do I get the model?

Answer (score 0):

There's no model associated to that table as the table is used directly in th e following models:

- Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php#L114
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php#L513
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php#L1209

Answer (score 0):

This table represents an association between the product model and the category model and is not a model by itself.

If you want to add products to a category, you can emulate what the corresponding admin controller is doing:

```
$category->setPostedProducts([
  $position1 => $productId1,
  $position2 => $productId2,
  ...
]);
$category->save();
```

If you want to select categories for a product, it's similar:

```
$product->setCategoryIds([
  $categoryId1,
  $categoryId2,
  ...
]);
$product->save();
```

**Both will replace all relations for the given category or product, not just add new ones!**

To insert arbitrary relations, you will have to use the table directly or write your own resource model for it.